# Unable to read csv file into R

Tags: r

When writing code

```
setwd("C:/LB2_Vladimirova")
t2 <- read.csv(file = "data_load_example.cvs", header = TRUE, sep = ';')
```

I'm getting an error

```
 setwd("C:/LB2_Vladimirova")
> t2 <- read.csv(file = "data_load_example.cvs", header = TRUE, sep = ';')
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'data_load_example.cvs': No such file or directory
```

Help please, with what it can be connected?

I tried to make the folder working, and saved the script itself in it, but nothing happens

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Could be a rights issue if the file is in that location, but it says it is not, it might not have access to actually check.

Comment: and how can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with r to know for sure, but in an IIS setting, there are some things you need to do to allow the website to access certain folers, as well as Virtual links to the folders so we can call them by a name and not the physical location.

Comment: If you use Rstudio and create a project in your folder, is that still an issue. Note that by using the project feature you don't need to use `setwd()`.

Comment: I don't think it's a permissions issue, that would give you a `cannot open file 'myfile.csv': Permission denied` error.  Are you sure the file exists in that location, and there is no type (you have .cvs instead of .csv in your example)?  You can verify that the file exists at the path by running `list.files('.')` after your `setwd()` command.

Comment: If you're running under Windows (guessing from your path structure): `file.choose(getwd())` will launch the file picker in the directory R considers its current working directory. Do you see `data_load_example.cvs` among the listed files? If not, there's the problem. If yes, cancel, and assign the filename as `fn <- file.choose()` (select desired file and confirm) and import like `read.csv(file = fn, ...)`

Comment: Is it `"data_load_example.cvs"` or `"data_load_example.csv"`? (c**vs** versus c**sv**)